# When describing location can ある take more than one に?

Tags: grammar, particle-に

> 村はずれの**山に近い所にある**小さな社{やしろ}が、がけくずれで流されたのだ。
>   The small shrine located in a place near the mountains on the edge of town had been washed away by a landslide.

I can't decide how to parse the part in bold. I can see two ways:

> 1) (山に近い所)にある社
>   2) (山に)(近い所に)ある社

For 1) I'm translating as "Shrine located in a place which is near to the mountains." i.e the place is **near** the mountains but not **in** the mountains.

For 2) I'm translating as "Shrine which is located in a nearby place, and is located in the mountains." i.e. the nearby place is **in** the mountains.

Is the sentence ambiguous or is one of these obviously wrong? And why?

I'm guessing at option 1) since I'm not sure you can have the structure AにBにある. But I think many shrines are located in the mountains so 2) seems possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sentence should be parsed like option 1. Grammatically, it's very similar to a sentence like

> (私は)駅に近い所に住んでいる (I live in a place that is near the station)

I think it can't be the option 2 because you would need to have 近い　before the part about 山に. So something like 近い山にある